# How to setup Asus MB168B USB monitor in Linux Mint?

Tags: usb, monitor, displaylink

is the first time I write here.

I bought an external usb monitor http://www.asus.com/it/Monitors_Projectors/MB168B/;

I have an Asus s56cb with dual boot, linux Mint 17 qiana and windows 7. On windows 7 the monitor work without problem, but on linux it doesn't work...when I insert the Usb, but nothing happen.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like another product with DisplayLink chips. <s>DisplayLink has no interest in supporting Linux, therefore</s> if you need a portable monitor that works with Linux buy a model that also has HDMI or DisplayPort connectivity.

By the way, Linux Mint is off-topic here.

Edit: Drivers for newer DisplayLink products have been released in mid 2015.

Comment: I apologize for the off-topic ... linux mint has the same architecture of ubuntu, so I was hoping to find a solution more easily on this site. 
Regarding the question, I have a colleague who has my same version of linux and uses a non-portable usb monitor the AOC (without hdmi like mine), so I thought that even the one I bought would work without problems.

Comment: I bought the MB168B+ and it work on linux but only on 1366*768. You have to use custom drivers available in DisplayLink forums